# How to use rBloomberg to create a data.frame of bar data

Tags: r, xts, bloomberg

I'm new to R, so please excuse any ignorance on my part. I have been search fruitlessly for several hours and I have to imagine that what I am trying to do is a common task. Basically, the Bloomberg API seems to only let you grab price bar data for one stock at a time. So if I have a list of tickers, I need to use a for loop to go through each ticker and grab the bar data. But what I really want to do is to have a single data.frame (I think) that has the datetime as the first column, and each column after that is the price data (say, the closing price) for a single stock, where all of these are aligned to the same list of datetimes. This is what I have so far, which doesn't work:

```
require(xts)
library(RBloomberg)
conn <- blpConnect()
start.date <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() - 20)
end.date <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
ticks <- c("AAPL US Equity", "XOM US Equity", "MSFT US Equity", "IBM US Equity")
pxdt <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(ticks)){ 
 x <- (ticks)[[i]]  
 print(x) 
 y <- (x) 
 y <- bar(conn, x , "TRADE", "2011-06-30 09:00:00.000", "2011-10-20 15:00:00.000", "60")
 px <- (y[6])
 pxdt <- cbind(px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's little hard to create something reproducible since most of us won't have Bloomberg access, but I think the manual already offers a lot: http://findata.org/rbloomberg/rbloomberg-manual-0-4-144.pdf , see 3. Requesting Data

```
securities <- c("AMZN US Equity", "OCN US Equity")
fields <- c("NAME", "PX_LAST", "TIME", "SETTLE_DT", "HAS_CONVERTIBLES")
# Demo different return data types.
bdp(conn, securities, fields)
```

Can't test but looks like that gives back a `data.frame`. So if that does not work for you.
What class / data does

```
bar(conn, "RYA ID Equity", "TRADE", "2010-09-21 09:00:00.000", "2010-09-21 15:00:00.000", "60")
```

return? Maybe you can post the output of `str(yourdata)` or class(yourdata) so we could tell you how to convert the result to a data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it looks like the bar function does not have the same capability to process multiple tickers at once. If I use the typeof(data) command on the output of running bar, it says it is a list. It looks like a table with 7 columns that gives a row.name column, the time, open/high/low/close price columns, numevents, and volume columns. I only want to grab the time and the close price from that and stuff it into some kind of object. Another issue is that different tickers will give back differently aligned time series, so I can't just glue together the outputs.

Comment: ok, if it's a `list`, you might wanna try `unlist(yourbaroutput)`.